# Sorting JavaScript generated image preview into filename numeric order (files are 1-xxx, 2-xxx etc)

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

Using a JS snippet I found here I am able to preview images prior to upload, here is that code...

```js
function previewImages() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  
  if (this.files) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
  }

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...
    
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var image = new Image();
      image.height = 85;
      image.title  = file.name;
      image.src    = this.result;
      preview.appendChild(image);
    });
    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
  }

}

document.querySelector('#file-input').addEventListener("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

My issue is despite the filenames of the images being uploaded being like 1-black, 2-red, 3-blue etc when they are previewed they are in a random order, the desired output would be to show them in alphabetical order.

I have been looking at `images.sort();` // use sort function of javascript. but can't figure out how to use it!

Comment: is the filename structure always same as 1-xxx and 3-xxx ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, the filenames will always start with numbers in the order they are to be displayed. 1-xxx, 2-xxx, 3-xxx etc

Comment: Just to confirm its the `-red` `-black` etc etc as the title you want to show in alphabetical order regardless of their selection from the folder ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, No it's by the number I require, so I should perhaps edit to say numerical order now I think about it!

Comment: small note: the extension doesn't tell you whether it's an image. Each format has its own magic number/header code.

Comment: you want to update the sort everytime a new images is append for example 10 was there but if you add new image you want 1 to be at the top ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping they are always uploaded in a batch of 12, non added afterwards, I want them to just be in numerical order on the preview

Comment: use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the FileReader